# Copy commands from webpage to Putty?

Tags: putty

couldn't find the answer on google so will give it a try here. How do I copy paste commands from webpages into Putty? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do Ctrl+c on the webpage and use your mouse's middle button on put or use shift +insert.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.

Comment: In case any of the above doesn't work, try clicking on both of the mouse buttons(left & right) at the same time to paste text in Putty.